# How to show only the first 20 entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, output, python-re

The Python code here gets me the output I want. However, I need help with limiting the result to first 20 lines.

Input example is shown below,

> gi|170079688|ref|YP_001729008.1| bifunctional riboflavin kinase/FMN adenylyltransferase [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. DH10B]
>   MKLIRGIHNLSQAPQEGCVLTIGNFDGVHRGHRALLQGLQEEGRKRNLPVMVMLFEPQPLELFATDKAPA
>   RLTRLREKLRYLAECGVDYVLCVRFDRRFAALTAQNFISDLLVKHLRVKFLAVGDDFRFGAGREGDFLLL
>   QKAGMEYGFDITSTQTFCEGGVRISSTAVRQALADDNLALAESLLGHPFAISGRVVHGDELGRTIGFPTA
>   NVPLRRQVSPVKGVYAVEVLGLGEKPLPGVANIGTRPTVAGIRQQLEVHLLDVAMDLYGRHIQVVLRKKI
>   RNEQRFASLDELKAQIARDELTAREFFGLTKPA
>   gi|170079689|ref|YP_001729009.1| isoleucyl-tRNA synthetase [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. DH10B]
>   MSDYKSTLNLPETGFPMRGDLAKREPGMLARWTDDDLYGIIRAAKKGKKTFILHDGPPYANGSIHIGHSV
>   NKILKDIIVKSKGLSGYDSPYVPGWDCHGLPIELKVEQEYGKPGEKFTAAEFRAKCREYAATQVDGQRKD
>   FIRLGVLGDWSHPYLTMDFKTEANIIRALGKIIGNGHLHKGAKPVHWCVDCRSALAEAEVEYYDKTSPSI
>   DVAFQAVDQDALKAKFAVSNVNGPISLVIWTTTPWTLPANRAISIAPDFDYALVQIDGQAVILAKDLVES
>   VMQRIGVTDYTILGTVKGAELELLRFTHPFMGFDVPAILGDHVTLDAGTGAVHTAPGHGPDDYVIGQKYG
>   LETANPVGPDGTYLPGTYPTLDGVNVFKANDIVVALLQEKGALLHVEKMQHSYPCCWRHKTPIIFRATPQ
>   WFVSMDQKGLRAQSLKEIKGVQWIPDWGQARIESMVANRPDWCISRQRTWGVPMSLFVHKDTEELHPRTL
>   ELMEEVAKRVEVDGIQAWWDLDAKEILGDEADQYVKVPDTLDVWFDSGSTHSSVVDVRPEFAGHAADMYL
>   EGSDQHRGWFMSSLMISTAMKGKAPYRQVLTHGFTVDGQGRKMSKSIGNTVSPQDVMNKLGADILRLWVA
>   STDYTGEMAVSDEILKRAADSYRRIRNTARFLLANLNGFDPAKDMVKPEEMVVLDRWAVGCAKAAQEDIL
>   KAYEAYDFHEVVQRLMRFCSVEMGSFYLDIIKDRQYTAKADSVARRSCQTALYHIAEALVRWMAPILSFT
>   ADEVWGYLPGEREKYVFTGEWYEGLFGLADSEAMNDAFWDELLKVRGEVNKVIEQARADKKVGGSLEAAV
>   TLYAEPELSAKLTALGDELRFVLLTSGATVADYNDAPADAQQSEVLKGLKVALSKAEGEKCPRCWHYTQD
>   VGKVAEHAEICGRCVSNVAGDGEKRKFA
>   gi|170079690|ref|YP_001729010.1| lipoprotein signal peptidase [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. DH10B]
>   MSQSICSTGLRWLWLVVVVLIIDLGSKYLILQNFALGDTVPLFPSLNLHYARNYGAAFSFLADSGGWQRW
>   FFAGIAIGISVILAVMMYRSKATQKLNNIAYALIIGGALGNLFDRLWHGFVVDMIDFYVGDWHFATFNLA
>   DTAICVGAALIVLEGFLPSRAKKQ

```
import re

id = None
header = None
seq = ''

a_file = open('e_coli.faa')

for line in a_file:
    m = re.match(">(\S+)\s+(.+)", line.rstrip())
    if m:
        if id is not None:

            print("{0} length:{1} {2}".format(id, len(seq),header))

        id, header = m.groups()
        seq = ''
    else:
        seq += line.rstrip()
```

Comment: Use the `slicing` operator on the `a_file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the very top, add `c = 0`. Then, change

```
        print("{0} length:{1} {2}".format(id, len(seq),header))
```

to

```
        if c < 10:
            print("{0} length:{1} {2}".format(id, len(seq),header))
            c += 1
```

Result with a few adjustments:

```
import re

id = None
header = None
seq = ''

with open('e_coli.faa') as a_file:
    for line in a_file:
        m = re.match(">(\S+)\s+(.+)", line.rstrip())
        if m:
            if id and c < 20:
                print("{0} length:{1} {2}".format(id, len(seq),header))
                c += 1

            id, header = m.groups()
            seq = ''
        else:
            seq += line.rstrip()
```

---

To read the first 20 lines of the file.
you can use `readlines()`:

Instead of:

```
for line in a_file:
```

use:

```
for line in a_file.readlines()[:20]:
```

Comment: This reads the first 20 lines of input file, but I need to print the first 20 lines of results instead.

Comment: I actually tried this approach earlier, but it's giving me an error "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" on the print line.